# Ceiling Lights Effect Using THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, light

I don't find any good example to do that so any help would be very useful :)

I want achieve this type of light in ceiling of my house object in Three.js

```
rectLight = new THREE.RectAreaLight( 0xffffff, 500, 10, 10 );
rectLight.position.set( 5, 5, 0 );
rectLightHelper = new THREE.RectAreaLightHelper( rectLight );
scene.add( rectLightHelper );
```

I have Tried all the light type for example pointLight , DirectionalLight , SpotLight and in last i found this ReactAreaLight but still i don't achieve this type of light in my three.js scene.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please visit the [help] and see what and [ask]. Hint: Post effort and code!

Comment: It's better to ask such question at forums (for example [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/)). Have you seen this [_official_ example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=light#webgl_lights_rectarealight)?

Comment: i also asked there but still got nothing.. :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply postprocessing. Try Effect Composer and BloomPass

```
//For adding additional effect an the top of rendering
function postprocessing() {
    renderScene = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);
    effectFXAA = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.FXAAShader);
    effectFXAA.uniforms['resolution'].value.set(1 / window.innerWidth, 1 / window.innerHeight);
    var copyShader = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.CopyShader);
    copyShader.renderToScreen = true;
    bloomPass = new THREE.UnrealBloomPass(new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight), 0.5, 0.1, 0.85); //( resolution, strenght, radius, threshold));
    composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
    composer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    composer.addPass(renderScene);
    composer.addPass(effectFXAA);
    composer.addPass(bloomPass);
    composer.addPass(copyShader);
}

// start the render loop
function render() {
    renderer.clear();
    composer.render();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    composer.render();
}
```

Comment: Just remember that the image you share have light map and AO map applied on it. You should do the same to get the closest result. And also with these map you can avoid the need of threejs lights.